# What does a resolver function look like that returns an enum in graphql-yoga?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

What does a resolver function look like that returns an enum in graphql-yoga? ‍♀️ I can't find any examples in their docs.

```
query{
  search() : CreateUrlResponse!
}

type CreateUrlResponse {
    searchResult: String!
    error: CreateUrlError
}

enum CreateUrlError {
  Error1
  Error2
}
```

resolver :

```
export const query = {

    async search(parent, args, ctx: Context, info) {
      ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
export const query = {
    search(parent, args, ctx: Context, info) {
      return {
        searchResult: "abc",
        error: "Error1",
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enums in GraphQL.js are effectively just a String that's just limited to some set of values. So you can just do:

```
return {
  searchResult: 'Foo',
  error: 'Error1',
}
```

Note: when using them in a request, their behavior will be slightly different:

```
someQuery(someString: "Foo")

someOtherQuery(someEnum: Foo)
```